# Which scripture is the source for this Achamanam?

Tags: scripture, mantras

From [this](http://nitaaiveda.com/All_Scriptures_By_Acharyas/Deity_Worship/Rama_Puja.htm) link:

> 2 acamana
>
> Om keshavaya svaha
>
> Om narayanaya svaha
>
> Om madhavaya svaha

I have noticed that this achamanam is popular mostly among Telugu speaking communities.

My question: Which scripture is the source for this achamanam?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Âchamana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Achamana)** is one of most rituals of Hindu religion and is performed before almost all brahmin rituals in order to gain purity of mind and body.

[Here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/db/bk11ch16.htm) is the explanation of **Âchamana** in **Devibhagwatpurana**

> *Firstly make the ordinary **Âchaman** three times, and, while inhaling, drink a little of the water of Âchaman, repeating **“Om Kes’avâya Svâhâ, Om Nârâyanâya Svâhâ, Om Mâdhavâya Svâhâ.**” Then wash your two hands, repeating “Om Gobindâya Namah, Om Visnave Namah.” Then by the root of the thumb rub the lips repeating “Om Madhû sûdanâya Namah, Om Trivikramâya Namah.” So rub the mouth, repeating “Om Vâmamâya Namah, Om S’rîdharâya Namah.” Then sprinkle water on the left hand, saying “Om Hrisîkes’âya Namah.” Sprinkle water on the legs, saying “Om Padmanâbhâya Namah.” Sprinkle water on the head, saying “Om Dâmodarâya Namah.” Touch the mouth with the three fingers of the right hand, saying “Om Samkarsanâya Namah.” Touch the nostrils with the thumb and forefinger saying “Om Vâsudevâya Namah, Om Pradyumnâya Namah.” Touch the eyes with the thumb and ring-finger, saying “Om Aniruddhâya Namah, Om Purusottamâya Namah.” Touch the ears with the thumb and ringfinger saying “Om Adhoksajâya Namah, Om Nârasimhâya Namah.” Touch the navel with the thumb and little finger saying “Om Achyutâya Namah.” Touch the breast with the palm, saying “Om Janârdanâya Namah.” Touch the head saying “Om Upendrâya Namah.” Touch the roots of the two arms saying “Om Haraye Namah, Om Krisnâya Namah.*”
>
> *While sipping the Âchaman water on the right hand, touch the right hand with your left hand; otherwise; the water does not become pure. While doing Âchaman, make the palm and the fingers all united and close, of the form of a Gokarna (the ear of a cow) and spreading the thumb and the little finger, drink the water of the measure of a pea. If a greater or less quantity be sipped, then that would amount to drinking liquor.*

Comment: Thanks Eshan for providing the source for the achamana.BTW,a lot of the associated things mentioned like touching the right hand with the left while sipping are not followed now a days.At least i have not seen any one doing that..

Comment: Can you pls tell which is the source for the achamana found in this link?:http://www.vjsingh.info/homa.html

Comment: @Rickross it's Taken from Taitiriya Aranyaka and many other Scriptures I'm not sure.

Comment: Eshan Singh can you tell me the source for this one as well?a variant of the achamana in the question(with namaha coming in place of swaha) found in point12 in this link:http://ommrudraksha.com/topic/14-how-to-energize-rudraksha-mala.aspx.

Comment: @Rickross check [this](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=O5JZBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT65&lpg=PT65&dq=Om+Keshavaya+Namaha&source=bl&ots=1PYY2SiqR0&sig=mnHF9TK_0QqoLzs6i91-KELRpZo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxlKDx3b_LAhVJbY4KHQaaDek4FBDoAQg4MAY#v=onepage&q=Om%20Keshavaya%20Namaha&f=false) link

Comment: What is the source of the other achamananam? The `om pranaya swaha, apanaaya swaaha, udanaaya swaha` one?